# MS SQL Server - Create schema dump without FILENAME property

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssms

I would like to create an SQL Server schema dump from a local server that I can run from within an sql server docker container to create an empty database ready for integration tests.

I generate the scripts via SQL Server Management Studio. I right click the database > Tasks > Generate script and set `Types of data to script` to "Schema only".

I copy the sql files across as part of my docker-compose.yml and when I run the sql dump from within the docker container I get

```
Directory lookup for the file 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydatabase.mdf" 
failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
```

the part of the script that's causing the above is...

```
CREATE DATABASE [mydatabase]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'mydatabase', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydatabase.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'mydatabase_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydatabase_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT
GO
```

If I go through the same generation process from an azure hosted database the create code generated is...

```
CREATE DATABASE [mydatabase]
GO
```

and if I manually run the above from within the container, it creates as expected.

So what do I need to do to generate an SQL schema dump that doesn't include the FILENAME property of the create command?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to tell SQL Server to not include the file arguments to `CREATE DATABASE` - you may want to omit the database altogether and add it manually or add a step where that path gets replaced at runtime with the path the container expects.

Comment: You'll need to do some search-replacing, or switch tools. The only way to get SSMS to script a `CREATE DATABASE` without any file specs is to actually tell it to generate scripts targeting SQL Azure as the version, but obviously that may result in a script that won't run successfully on an on-premise instance of SQL Server (including one running in a container).

Comment: Thanks both, surprised at that to be honest! I guess then my followup would be can I generate a script that includes everything as before except the CREATE DATABASE and ALTER DATABASE lines?

Comment: Sure -- instead of scripting "entire database and all database objects", choose "specific database objects" and then just select everything. That will script everything *in* the database, but not the DB itself. If you're planning to integrate this in a development pipeline I would suggest switching to things like SSDT database projects/DACPACs, though, as they're designed for this and `sqlpackage` is command-line friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Jeroen Mostert's suggestion I generate the scripts without the CREATE DATABASE part, this is done by selecting "specific database objects" instead of "entire database and all database objects"

I then run a script I manually wrote that creates all the required databases, followed by running the scripts that create the tables and procedures against each database.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=true
      - SA_PASSWORD=localdevpassword#123
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/scripts/
    ports:
      - "1434:1433"
    command: /bin/bash -c /scripts/init.sh
```

**init.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting SQL server"
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
echo "Sleeping for 10 seconds"
sleep 10
echo "Done sleeping, run the SQL scripts"
cd /scripts/
echo "Creating databases using file databases.sql"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -l 30 -e -i databases.sql
for FILENAME in *.sql; do
  DATABASE="${FILENAME%.*}"
  if [ "$DATABASE" != "databases" ]; then
    echo "Running import for $DATABASE using file $FILENAME"
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d $DATABASE -l 30 -e -i $FILENAME
  fi  
done 
echo "SQL scripts run, sleep forever to keep container running"
sleep infinity
```